# How to detect when my Chrome extension panel is in focus?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension with `chrome.devtools.panels.create`.

Now I want to detect inside of the extension code when the panel is open.

I tried:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
  console.log("port", port);
});
```

but I cannot find a method that would work.

I also tried `visibilitychange`, but it detects the main tab visibility, rather than the devtools tab.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  console.log("visibilitychange", document.visibilityState);
});
```

MDN mentions [`browser.devtools.panels.onShown.addListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/devtools/panels/ExtensionSidebarPane/onShown), which sounds like what I want, but `browser` global does not exist in Chrome extension context.

The goal is enable/disable content script based on whether the extension tab is open in DevTools.

Comment: Just replace browser with chrome. Note that Chrome has its [own documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels) for its extension API.